# Random Number Generator C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get my program to start the user with 20 lives and while Lives is greater than 0, flip a coin (random number generator 0(Tails) or 1(Heads)). Every time the user gets Heads it adds 1 to Heads counter and 1 to Flips counter. Every time the user gets Tails it takes 1 from Lives and adds 1 to Flips counter. I think my only problem is my random number generator!? Please be kind, total n00b :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Coin_Flip_2015
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
   private Random r = new Random(1);
    private void cmdFlipCoin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int rand = r.Next(1);
        int Heads;
        int counterFlips;
        int Lives;

        Lives = 20;
        Heads = 0;
        counterFlips = 0;

        while (Lives > 0)
            if (rand == 0)
            {
                Lives = Lives -= 1;
                counterFlips++;
            }

            else if (rand == 1)
            {
                Heads = Heads += 1;
                counterFlips++;
            }

        lblFlips.Text = "Flips = " + counterFlips.ToString();
        lblHeads.Text = "Heads = " + Heads.ToString();
        lblLivesLeft.Text = "Lives Left = " + Lives.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show("sorry you are out of lives m8");
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Form.png]

Comment: What is the actual problem? How is it not working compared to how you expect?

Comment: You shouldn't have while loops inside UI threads, you will potentially loop forever causing your application to stop responding.

Comment: Starting with 20 and having 50/50 probability you will never get to zero.

Comment: No one pointed out that rand is only set once so it will never change too.

Comment: You also don't have to do `Lives = Lives -= 1`, You just do `Lives -= 1`, also, in the `else` you are changing "heads" not lives.

Comment: You may want to use `private Random r = new Random();` if you want things to be random each time you run your form.

Comment: @RonBeyer I know ;)   It would be better to rand 100 then % (mod) for a remainder to get a better sample rate

Answer (score 1):

The [`Random.Next(int)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zd1bc8e5(v=vs.110).aspx) method

> Returns a non-negative random integer that is less than the specified maximum.

So `r.Next(1)` is always 0. Use `r.Next(2)` to get 0 or 1.

You should also move the `rand = r.Next(1);` inside the `while` loop. Now it's only assigned once, at the beginning of the method.

Comment: fyi, it will always be what it was set to and does not change as it is outside the while loop

Comment: @Sorceri Right, as soon as I read 'random 0/1' in the question I quickly scanned the code for `Next(1)` ignoring everything else. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a swing at fixing all the issues:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int Heads, counterFlips, Lives;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Lives = 20;
        Heads = 0;
        counterFlips = 0;
    }

    private Random r = new Random();

    private void cmdFlipCoin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int rand = r.Next(2);

        if (Lives > 0)
        {
            if (rand == 0)
            {
                Lives -= 1;
                counterFlips++;
            }
            else
            {
                Heads += 1;
                counterFlips++;
            }
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("sorry you are out of lives m8");

        lblFlips.Text = "Flips = " + counterFlips.ToString();
        lblHeads.Text = "Heads = " + Heads.ToString();
        lblLivesLeft.Text = "Lives Left = " + Lives.ToString();
    }
}
```

Issues:

- The `Heads`, `counterFlips` and `Lives` variables were stored locally, they need to be global
- The code was changed so that you flip a coin each time you click the button (changed the `while` to an `if`). `while` loops that have the capability of never exiting should not be used in UI threads.
- `private Random r = new Random()` notice removed the 1, use the default constructor to seed it properly.
- Added an "else" to show when the lives were used, it shows your message
- Changed the `Lives = Lives -= 1` (same with Heads) to proper code
- Used `r.Next(2)` to get either 0 or 1, since the upper bound is exclusive.

Other than that, I'm not sure what you are doing with the `Lives` and `Heads` numbers, so I'll leave that up to you to fix.

Comment: Thanks so much for all the feedback guys, just started programming a few weeks ago and I am just working my way through a workbook asking me to do certain tasks. It is not the best workbook. Clearly I need to spend much more time on this. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

Here one that is a bit different.. *snap* beat me by a few seconds!

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // Leave the seed alone on this line
    private readonly Random _r = new Random();

    // these need to be outside of your Click event
    private int _counterFlips;
    private int _heads;
    private int _lives = 20;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void cmdFlipCoin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // x = starting number, y = ending number + 1
        // This should be either a zero or one:
        int rand = _r.Next(0, 2);

        switch (rand)
        {
            default:
                _lives --;
                _counterFlips++;
                break;
            case 1:
                _heads ++;
                _counterFlips++;
                break;
        }

        if (_lives < 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(@"sorry you are out of lives m8");
            button1.Enabled = false;
            return;
        }


        lblFlips.Text = @"Flips = " + _counterFlips;
        lblHeads.Text = @"Heads = " + _heads;
        lblLivesLeft.Text = @"Lives Left = " + _lives;

    }
}
```